# Django: No Module named 'foo' issue in context with model import

Tags: python, django

**Background information:** 
I would like to run the `feeder.py` script using atoms `script` plug-in. I **first** encountered a `ImproperlyConfigured` error which was solved as suggested here: [First fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59152742/atom-script-add-on-doesnt-recognize-django-model-settings-when-running-a-scri)

Then I run into `RuntimeError: Model class models.AccountInformation doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.` error which was solved by using an absolute path for the model import as shown below.

**Current issue:** 
Using the mentioned absolute import, I receive this error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Dashboard_app'`

I can even render the template for that app etc. so I am confused why he tells me that the module doesn't exist. When I remove the model import, everything works just fine. Is it maybe that the `script` instance doesn't recognize it properly?

**What I've tried:**

- deleted + re-created `__init__.py`
- checked settings for app to be included in `INSTALLED-APPS` dic
- changed import path to `DASHEX.Dashboard_app.models` resulting in `no module named DASHEX` error
- changed import path to `models` resulting in `Model class models.AccountInformation doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS` error
- changed the app in `INSTALLED_APPS` to `Dashboard_app`

**feeder.py script:**

```
import django
from django.conf import settings
import zmq
import time
from time import sleep
import uuid
settings.configure()
django.setup()
import sys
print(sys.path)
from Dashboard_app.models import AccountInformation
[...]
```

**settings.py:**

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    #other Apps
    'Wiki_app',
    'rest_framework',
    'Dashboard_app.apps.DashboardAppConfig'
]
```

**Models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
import uuid

# Create your models here.


class AccountInformation(models.Model):
    version = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    DID = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    accountNumber = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    broker = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    leverage = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False)
    account_balance = models.FloatField(max_length=15, blank=False)
    account_profit = models.FloatField(max_length=15, blank=False)
    account_equity = models.FloatField(max_length=15, blank=False)
    account_margin = models.FloatField(max_length=15, blank=False)
    account_margin_free = models.FloatField(max_length=15, blank=False)
    account_margin_leve = models.FloatField(max_length=15, blank=False)
    account_currency = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'AccountInfo'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.accountNumber
```

**Project structure:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (almost sure!) that the problem is about the `settings.configure()`; as you didn't specify any `default_settings`, django will use it's *default* settings template (the one you see when you create a new project) and your `Dashboard_app` is not there. That's the cause of this error:

> changed import path to models resulting in Model class models.AccountInformation doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS error

Try specifiying your settings inside the `configure`:

```
from dashex import settings

settings.configure(settings)
```

Comment: That's it. Your are a god!